# Object Casting / ObjectiveC from Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have this code in Objective C (it's an extract of Apple AdvancedCollectionView source code)

```
@interface AAPLCollectionViewWrapper : NSObject

+ (UIView *)wrapperForCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView mapping:(AAPLDataSourceMapping *)mapping
{
   if (!collectionView)
    return nil;

   BOOL measuring = NO;

   if ([collectionView isKindOfClass:[AAPLCollectionViewWrapper class]])
     measuring = ((AAPLCollectionViewWrapper *)collectionView).measuring;

   return (UIView *)[[AAPLCollectionViewWrapper alloc] initWithCollectionView:collectionView mapping:mapping measuring:measuring];
}
```

I try to translate it in swift but i have a problem with this line :

```
return (UIView *)[[AAPLCollectionViewWrapper alloc] initWithCollectionView:collectionView mapping:mapping measuring:measuring];
```

In Swift

```
return (CollectionViewWrapper(collectionView: collectionView, mapping: mapping, measuring: measuring) as! UIView
```

I have this error **Cast from 'CollectionViewWrapper' to unrelated type 'UIView' always fails**

What's wrong ? How can i convert my APPLCollectionViewWrapper to UIView ?

**UPDATED**

I think i need to use polymorphism, in the original source code, i have found this comment :

```
/// An object that pretends to be either a UITableView 
/// or UICollectionView that handles transparently mapping from local to global index paths
@interface AAPLCollectionViewWrapper : NSObject
```

So in the source code, the AAPLCollectionViewWrapper is an NSObject, the function wrapperForCollectionView return a UIView, then it's cast to an UICollectionView

.h

```
/// An object that pretends to be either a UITableView or UICollectionView that handles transparently mapping from local to global index paths
@interface AAPLCollectionViewWrapper : NSObject

/// Factory method that will determine whether the wrapper is measuring based on the collection view. If the collectionView is actually an instance of AAPLCollectionViewWrapper, the value will be pulled from the collectionView. Otherwise, the default is NO.
+ (__kindof UIView *)wrapperForCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView mapping:(nullable AAPLDataSourceMapping *)mapping;

+ (__kindof UIView *)wrapperForCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView mapping:(nullable AAPLDataSourceMapping *)mapping measuring:(BOOL)measuring;

@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) UICollectionView *collectionView;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, strong, readonly) AAPLDataSourceMapping *mapping;

@property (nonatomic, readonly) BOOL measuring;

@end
```

How I can make the same thing in swift?

Comment: I don't know much about the `AdvancedCollectionView`. But I think if it is a `CollectionViewWrapper`, there should be a way to get the thing that it wraps. Try to find that property/method that unwraps the wrapper. Then you'll get a `CollectionView`. You can then directly return this `CollectionView`, no need to cast!

Comment: Write your CollectionViewWrapper class in swift

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to consider "pipe" model, so that your wrapper has to be UICollectionView itself - need to be derived from UICollectionView:

```
@interface AAPLCollectionViewWrapper : UICollectionView
//...

+ (UICollectionView *)wrapperForCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView mapping:(AAPLDataSourceMapping *)mapping
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

> Cast from 'CollectionViewWrapper' to unrelated type 'UIView' always
>   fails

The compiler says it will always fails but not at run time. If it's really a kind of UIView, it won't fail at run time. And `AAPLCollectionViewWrapper` is an Objective-C expression, maybe extension of `UICollectionView` will be elegant.